# How to select specific data frames from a list to apply a function/plot in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

This should be simple, but I can't quite get it. I already learned how to use lapply to apply functions to an entire list of data frames (although I am still struggling to output the titles as the names of the dataframes, kinda just gave up on that and add the titles separately), but I can't seem to figure out how to specify just ONE dataframe from a list to apply a function such as ggplot.

I could just break up the list, but that seems to just defeat the purpose of making a list in the first place. Is there a simple way to do this? My list contains 4 data frames that are were created as "name = name".

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to extract a single data.frame from a list, is that right? If so, you can use double brackets to extract `[[`. For example, if your list is called `lst`, use `lst[[1]]` to extract the first data.frame, or `lst[["mtcars"]]` if your named list included a data.frame with that name. Then, you can include that as your source of data for a function, such as `ggplot(data = lst[[1]]...`. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi @Ben What about if i want to select 2 out of n dataframes? I tried lst[["mtcars", "mtcars2"]] but it doesn't work, also tried to use a vector inside brackets but it didn't

Comment: @Rene Martinez Try using a single bracket `[` that allows you to select more than one element. For example, `lst[c("mtcars", "mtcars2")]`